# Each Kaa Node in the cluster needs to have a separate Public IP address?

Tags: kaa

I am trying to setup a Kaa cluster with 3 kaa-node servers. I would like to know whether each node (bootstrap service & operations_service) must have its own public IP address？ Otherwise the endpoint will not be able to access them？
But I have only one Public IP address & one Domain Name. Each node has it's own local ip address. How can I setup this kaa-cluster?

Answer (score 0):

on each node:

1. open `kaa-node.properties` file at `/etc/kaa-node/conf` directory.
2. change **thrift_host** and **transport_public_interface** properties onto the local IP address.

Then you need to integrate kaa-node with the following services: 
 `Zookeeper`, `SQL` and `NoSQL` databases.
For more information, refer to the following documentation [page](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Cluster-setup/).

As alternative, you are able to setup kaa cluster using docker environment. Also, look to the documentation [page](http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Administration-guide/System-installation/Docker-deployment/#cluster-node-installation).
Please, take into account that docker extension is supported from kaa 0.10 version.